# Replace form field error text?

Tags: errors

I am customizing a multisite installation of Wordpress, and I want to replace this text.

```
Site names can only contain lowercase letters (a-z) and numbers.
```

Problem is that this is in the core of Wordpress and I cannot find any hook for it?
Do you have any idea on how to edit this with PHP? Or do I have to use some kind of CSS text replacement?

Thank you in advance!

The error appears under the `blogname-field`

Comment: What are you trying to change it to and why?

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to chage it with this:

```
function replace_registration_site_name_error( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
$default = 'Site names can only contain lowercase letters (a-z) and numbers.';
if ( $translated_text == $default ) {
    $translated_text = __( 'Test', 'my_text_domain' );
}
return $translated_text;
}
```

This works great.
However I am not able to change these two strings with this method?

```
Site name must be at least %s character.
Site name must be at least %s characters.
```

Anyone know why?